# How to fill color x with varying alpha with axhspan

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to fill red between two lines with the alpha of the reds changing based on a list. Essentially a custom gradient of reds, but it's the alpha that makes the red appear darker or lighter.

reproducible example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(range(20))
y = [8,9,12,14] # respective y values
a = [0.3,0.1,0.5,0.7]
ax.axhspan(8, 14, alpha=0.5, color='red')

plt.show()
```

[image: plot]

this may be useful in determining the colours required as it turns rgb to rgba. Maybe there's a way to map these colours between the two lines using axhspan?

```
from matplotlib.colors import to_rgb
r, g, b = to_rgb('red')
alpha_arr = a
c = [(r, g, b, alpha) for alpha in alpha_arr]
```

Comment: You can call `axhspan` in a loop, each time with a different alpha.  Note that your question doesn't specify at which x-values (or y-values?) you want to have which alpha.

Comment: @johanC . ive edited it to have sample y-values. that's a good idea. in my actual data set I have 5000+ alpha values and am producing several 100s graphs, so I would like it to be more efficient ideally.

Comment: Alpha only work well for large areas with an equal alpha.  In matplotlib (any many other softwares), alpha just mixes the background color (white in this example) with the new color (red). This only works for entire pixels, not the subpixels you'd get with 5000 ultra-thin spans.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get smooth gradients, you can use interpolation. To avoid problems with thin bands and alpha, you can use `imshow` (or maybe `pcolor`) instead:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
import numpy as np

a = [0.3, 0.1, 0.5, 0.7]
y = [8, 9, 12, 14]

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(14, 5))

ax1.plot(range(20))
bounds = np.linspace(y[0], y[-1], 100)
for b0, b1 in zip(bounds[:-1], bounds[1:]):
    ax1.axhspan(b0, b1, alpha=np.interp((b0 + b1) / 2, y, a), facecolor='red', edgecolor='none')
ax1.set_title('Using many thin axhspans')

ax2.plot(range(20))
xmin, xmax = ax2.get_xlim()
ymin, ymax = ax2.get_ylim()
cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('', ['white', 'red'])
ax2.imshow(np.interp(np.linspace(y[0], y[-1], 100), y, a).reshape(-1, 1),
           cmap=cmap, vmin=0, vmax=1,
           extent=[xmin, xmax, y[0], y[-1]], origin='lower',
           interpolation='bilinear', aspect='auto', zorder=-1)
ax2.set_xlim(xmin, xmax)
ax2.set_ylim(ymin, ymax)
ax2.set_title('Using imshow')
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: gradient with imshow vs axhspan]

Answer (score 0):

```
for x,a in enumerate(a):
  ax.axhspan(y[-1+x], y[0+x], alpha=a, color='red')
```

[image]

Comment: depending on your needs, you could also set `edgecolor='None'` to remove those darker horizontal lines between the different zones

Comment: Also note that you have 4 boundaries in `y`, which only separate 3 regions.